# Krohnkite, terminator, and laptop sleep mode broken

Tags: kubuntu, kde, backup

Something happened to my Linux desktop. I'm using kubuntu 20.04 and kde plasma 5.18.5 and I have krohnkite installed. Just now I used my laptop but whenever I open apps they don't tile. Krohnkite is supposed to tile windows but it doesn't. And another problem I use terminator as my terminal emulator and I usually set it to have a transparent background but now it's just a black background despite in settings it says it's 0.8 shade transparent background. My kernel is 5.4.0. I used xanmod before I think it was 5.10 something like that, does that impact anything? I tried using a TimeShift backup but it didn't fix anything. Does that mean it's a root or home file config that messed something up cuz I left those folders out of timeshift backup? I have an external hard drive connected to my laptop and usually when I set it to sleep the light on the HDD turns off but now it won't until I unplug the laptop from the wall outlet. Could power management be a part of the problem as well? My laptop has an athlon silver 3050u and 4 gb of ram, if that's helpful.

Edit: How can I fix the issues that I have stated?

Comment: I do not see a single clear question in any of that.

Comment: I was asking about how I can fix those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the fix, it turns out my compositor crashed. So all I had to do was to restart it.